# Can the most general unifier be defined categorically?

Tags: programming-languages, category-theory, unification

I remember from my reading of [Category Theory for Computing Science](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/triples/Barr-Wells-ctcs.pdf) that classical concepts like weakest preconditions can be seen as the categorical notion of pullback.

I was wondering if the same is true for the notion of [most general unifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)).

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.3615

Comment: There's certainly a trivial way in which the mgu can be seen categorically: it is the initial element in the category of unifiers...

Comment: I would also note this work http://umu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:142802/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: @cody the category of unifiers, whose morphisms are ...?

Comment: @Rodrigo: just substitutions.

Comment: Barr and wells give unifier in terms of coequalizer